# What is the most effiecient way to store data to a file -> read that data (print it) -> remove data

Tags: python

I am new to python and i was wondering what is a good way to do the following:

1. save output from my code into a file e.g. words.txt
2. read that data and print it out
3. remove all data from the file so that it is new and can be used again in step 1

I have tried using the following code, but i do not think it is well structured.

```
with open("words.txt", "w") as k:
    k.write(text[:-1])

with open("words.txt", "r") as p:
    content = p.read()
    print(content)
    p.close()

with open("words.txt", "w") as z:
    z.write(text[:-1])`
```

Comment: To start, you already have the data you just wrote to the file in memory. You don't need to read it back from the file before using it again.

Comment: What don't you like about the structure?

Comment: Why are you writing the same data to the same file twice in a row?

Answer (score 0):

```
content = text[:-1]

with open("words.txt", "w") as k:
    k.write(content)

with open("words.txt", "w") as z:
    z.write(content)
```

This is the only reduction of your code which actually makes sense... but if you wanted to read from the file, that syntax is probably the best one.

```
file = open("words.txt", "w")
file.write(text[:-1])
file.close()
```

Doing like this will let you avoid the `with`/`as` structure, but I don't think it's better.

Comment: `with`/`as` will save you some trouble if an error happens before closing the file (e.g. `text` is not defined or can't be indexed, etc.)

Comment: Right, feel free to add this edit directly to the answer if you want.